# Customizing Django login template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to Django and I want to use my custom login page instead of the ugly looking django login template. How could I make it work? I think I need to edit the urls.py file and override the login template but I don't know how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    LoginView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='login/login.html'), name='login'),
]
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
```

Now make a templates folder in the Base directory( where your `manage.py` is present) and in that folder make a new folder named `login`. Inside `login` folder make `login.html`

So the directory structure will be like this

```
-my_project
    -templates
        -login
            -login.html
    -manage.py
```

Now do whatever customization you want to do in `login.html`. You will get `form` object in context of the template, which is nothing but your login form.